# PHP ECHO to pass two Var's via URL

Tags: php, url, variables, echo

```
echo "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick='load_page_device(\"mg-device.php?device=device_name&sensor=$p1_url\")'>".$row['p1_name']."</a></li>";
```

Alright I simply trying to pass two variables in a url via a php echo statement. It's simply not working.

I am then using

```
$device_name = $_GET['device']; 
$sensor_name = $_GET['sensor'];
```

I have tried also to use & instead of & only. The first variable always seems to get passed but the second one never does. Any help is greatly appreciated I have been trying to get this to work for hours now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="load_page_device("mg-device.php?device=device_name&sensor="'.$p1_url.'")">'.$row['p1_name'].'</a></li>';
```

you need to first check that `$_GET['device'] , $_GET['sensor']`  is set

try

```
if(isset($_GET['device']) && isset($_GET['sensor'])){

//stuff

}else{
      //other stuff
}
```

Comment: $_GET['device'] is able to be echod back to me so that is being set, however $_GET['sensor'] is not.

Comment: it mean $_GET['sensor'] isnt set

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I am looking for. The variables are being passed to the next page and I have the echo statements to see if anything is being set already. Would this do something different then that? All I see is an if statement that would then run the echo which I don't need to do.

Comment: I know $_GET['sensor'] isnt set heh that's the problem! : )

Comment: I get the idea of the variables being checked with isset, however I just need them to be passed to the next page. That is the issue.

Comment: @user1707616 it is the way to do . suppose you are using those variable anywhere and not set than that that time it will show the error ... its better to check whether the $_GET.$_POST ...etc varible is set or not ..it will make you code less buggy and easy to debug

Comment: Well what I am thinking is that the $_GET variables will not be set until I click the <a href> link. Then once the link is clicked the page refreshes and then the variables should be set for $_GET

Comment: yup got it i mistakenly typed in if

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20370/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-user1707616)